# Android webview not displaying CSS gradient

Tags: android, css, webview

I have an HTML that looks fine in a chrome or IE browser, but when I host it on an Android webview, the gradient does not show.

```
.gradientback{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:8px;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(135,135,135,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(135,135,135,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(135,135,135,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(135,135,135,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(135,135,135,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(135,135,135,1) 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0089fff1', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }
```

I'm currently running 6.0 on my device, my genymotion isn't working or else I'd test it on different versions, but I assume they face a similar problem.

Thanks, and in case this may help, here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joz7j9ke/) with some gradient.